# Select a list from a list of lists based on how often their elements are present

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list of lists as an example:

```
L1 = {{1, 2, 4, 7}, {1, 7, 12, 15}, {1, 13, 3, 2}, {1, 15, 14, 13}, {2, 3, 23, 4}, {3, 13, 20, 24}, {3, 24, 22, 23}, {4, 8, 6, 7}, {4, 23, 32, 8}, {5, 6, 8, 31}, {5, 9, 10, 12}, {5, 12, 7, 6}, {5, 31, 28, 9}, {8, 32, 30, 31}, {9, 27, 11, 10}, {9, 28, 26, 27}, {10, 11, 15, 12}, {11, 16, 14, 15}, {11, 27, 17, 16}, {13, 14, 16, 20}, {16, 17, 18, 20}, {17, 25, 19, 18}, {17, 27, 26, 25}, {18, 19, 24, 20}, {19, 21, 22, 24}, {19, 25, 29, 21}, {21, 29, 30, 32}, {21, 32, 23, 
 22}, {25, 26, 28, 29}, {28, 31, 30, 29}};
```

I want to write something that gives the following selection as output:

```
Lnew = {{4, 23, 32, 8}, {5, 31, 28, 9}, {11, 27, 17, 16}, {19, 25, 29, 21}, {12, 15, 1, 7}, {3, 13, 20, 24} };
```

The criteria are as follows:
Each number from Lnew should be present 4x in the original list of lists L1.

For example, the number 4 is four times present in L1: {1, 2, 4, 7}, {2, 3, 23, 4}, {4, 8, 6, 7} and {4, 23, 32, 8}.

The number 3 is only three times present in L1: {2, 3, 23, 4}, {3, 13, 20, 24} and {3, 24, 22, 23}. Similarly, the number 7 is also only present three times. The numbers 23, 32 and 8 are four times present. Therefore, only {4,23,32,8} should be present in the new list.

Does anyone know how I (a beginner in Mathematica) can tackle this without using too advanced code?
Thank you :)

Comment: What's the extra structure for? Why isn't `Lnew` just `{4, 23, 32, 8, 5, 31, 28, 9, 11, 27, 17, 16, 19, 25, 29, 21, 12, 15, 1, 7, 3, 13, 20, 24}`

Comment: "Therefore, only {4,23,32,8} should be present in the new list". But that's not the case. `Lnew` has 6 lists of 4 elements each.

Comment: Based on just the textual description, this would be pretty easy starting with something like `Select[Counts[Flatten@L1], EqualTo[4]]`, but since I don't understand the extra structure, I'm not sure that's an acceptable answer.

Comment: "a beginner in Matlab". Did you mean "Mathematica"?

Comment: Woops yes mathematica.

Comment: Oh, I think I see. The `{4,23,32,8}` is already in `L1`. So, were selecting elements from `L1` that satisfy the criteria that each of their elements appears 4 times in the whole of `L1`.

Comment: They are faces for polyhedra. I want to visualise the polyhedron by only showing the faces of certain quadrilaterals. I only want to show the faces that have vertices that join three quadrilaterals. Lnew  should show the faces that have four vertices that join four quadrilaterals.

Comment: Yes your last comment is what I meant. Sorry for the confusing explanation. An example of such a polyhedron is George Harts propello cube: http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/PropelloCube.html. I want to also extend this to other propello polyhedra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
L1 = {{1, 2, 4, 7}, {1, 7, 12, 15}, {1, 13, 3, 2}, {1, 15, 14, 
    13}, {2, 3, 23, 4}, {3, 13, 20, 24}, {3, 24, 22, 23}, {4, 8, 6, 
    7}, {4, 23, 32, 8}, {5, 6, 8, 31}, {5, 9, 10, 12}, {5, 12, 7, 
    6}, {5, 31, 28, 9}, {8, 32, 30, 31}, {9, 27, 11, 10}, {9, 28, 26, 
    27}, {10, 11, 15, 12}, {11, 16, 14, 15}, {11, 27, 17, 16}, {13, 
    14, 16, 20}, {16, 17, 18, 20}, {17, 25, 19, 18}, {17, 27, 26, 
    25}, {18, 19, 24, 20}, {19, 21, 22, 24}, {19, 25, 29, 21}, {21, 
    29, 30, 32}, {21, 32, 23, 22}, {25, 26, 28, 29}, {28, 31, 30, 
    29}};

items2bRemoved = Counts[Flatten[L1]] // Select[# != 4 &] // Keys 

DeleteCases[L1, _?(ContainsAny[items2bRemoved])]
```

> {{1, 7, 12, 15}, {3, 13, 20, 24}, {4, 23, 32, 8}, {5, 31, 28, 9}, {11,
> 27, 17, 16}, {19, 25, 29, 21}}

Comment: Could I also make a new list of lists containing the {a,b,c,d} lists that were deleted using this method? That would be L2 = {{1, 2, 4, 7}, {1, 13, 3, 2}, {1, 15, 14, 13}, {2, 3, 23, 4}, {3, 24, 
  22, 23}, {4, 8, 6, 7}, {5, 6, 8, 31}, {5, 9, 10, 12}, {5, 12, 7, 
  6}, {8, 32, 30, 31}, {9, 27, 11, 10}, {9, 28, 26, 27}, {10, 11, 15, 
  12}, {11, 16, 14, 15}, {13, 14, 16, 20}, {16, 17, 18, 20}, {17, 25, 
  19, 18}, {17, 27, 26, 25}, {18, 19, 24, 20}, {19, 21, 22, 24}, {21, 
  29, 30, 32}, {21, 32, 23, 22}, {25, 26, 28, 29}, {28, 31, 30, 29}}.

Comment: @PTeeuwen, Use `Cases` instead of `DeleteCases`.

Answer (score 5):

```
With[
  {counts = Counts[Flatten@L1]},
  Select[L1, Lookup[counts, #] === {4, 4, 4, 4} &]]
```

Comment: Thank you! I just found another option that I posted in a comment.

Answer (score 4):

```
Select[MinMax[Count[L1, #, 2] & /@ #] == {4, 4} &] @L1
```

> ```
> {{1, 7, 12, 15}, {3, 13, 20, 24}, {4, 23, 32, 8}, {5, 31, 28, 9},   
>  {11, 27, 17, 16}, {19, 25, 29, 21}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question here:

This seems to work.

```
Lnew = { };
For[i = 0, i<= Length[L1]-1, i++;
    n = { };
    For[j = 0, j<= Length[L1[[i]]]-1, j++;
        AppendTo[n, Count[Flatten[L1], L1[[i]][[j]]]]
        ]
    If[AllTrue[n, # == 4&], AppendTo[Lnew, L1[[i]]]
        ]
    ]
Lnew
```